# Router not correctly loading default route on application load

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I've been struggling with this issue for the past day and a half and still have made no progress. Currently, I am attempting to load my angular app and have it default to a particular page when the application is bootstrapped. Unfortunately, it redirects to a different route.

I'm trying to go to:
`https://clwd0002278/ControlTower/NICK/UI/#/`

When I initially load, though, it goes to `https://clwd0002278/ControlTower/NICK/UI/#/ControlTower/NICK/UI/`, which results in the 404 page being hit.

I'll also try to go to `https://clwd0002278/ControlTower/NICK/UI/` with the same result as above.

Here's the code so someone can try to make sense of this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'patients', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
    {path: 'notifications', component: NotificationsComponent},
    {path: 'patients', component: PatientListComponent},
    {path: '404', component: NotFoundComponent},
    {path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent},
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

Here's the base-href on the html page:

```
<base href="#">
```

I have tried changing `base-href` and `deploy-url` in the build script, as well as omitting them entirely. I'm just not sure what I'm missing at this point.

Any help would be appreciated, and just ask if you need more information.

Edit:

The application exists at `https://clwd0002278/ControlTower/NICK/UI/` and **NOT** at `https://clwd0002278/`.

Comment: Everything after the # is never sent to the server... so the mentioned links all go to the same page

Comment: @patrick I know. But I'm expecting that when I load `https://clwd0002278/ControlTower/NICK/UI/` or `https://clwd0002278/ControlTower/NICK/UI/#/` it will bootstrap the app at that location instead of trying to do `https://clwd0002278/ControlTower/NICK/UI/#/ControlTower/NICK/UI/`

Comment: That sounds like a server config problem, not a programming problem. You might want to move this question to the appropriate part of stackoverflow (server fault)

Comment: There isn't a server that's serving this up. It's literally just the compiled files sitting in a directory and then I navigate to that directory in a browser to load it and this is how it loads.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<head>
  <base href="/ControlTower/NICK/UI">
  ...
</head>
```

to your `index.html`

or provide int in AppModule like

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
...

providers: [{APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/ControlTower/NICK/UI'}]
```

See also

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base
- https://angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF

Comment: If I try it as `/ControlTower/NICK/UI` in the base-href, it gives me this error for all files: `Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://clwd0002278/ControlTower/NICK/main.bundle.js”.`

If I try it as `/ControlTower/NICK/UI/`, it leads me back to where I was before. I've been trying this in every possible combination, but to no avail. Oddly enough, if I set the app up to serve from this environment, it'll work just fine... I have NOT been able to get that to extend to the remote server, though.

Actually, it doesn't work with serve either.

Comment: If `<base>` causes conflicts with other HTML stuff, then use `APP_BASE_HREF`, that only affects the Angular router.

Comment: I added it with base-href set to '#' and just adding in the provider, but it came back as this: `https://clwd0002278/ControlTower/NICK/UI/#/ControlTower/NICK/UI/ControlTower/NICK/UI/`

Comment: Why "with base-href set to '#'"?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you are using `useHash: true`. In this case you shouldn't need a base-href.

Comment: If I set base-href to '/' else, I get this result: `http://localhost:4200/#/ControlTower/NICK/UI/patients`, which surprisingly is loading patients as the default like it's supposed to, but then the hash mark is in the incorrect location, although, I'm not certain if that's a bad thing yet...

Comment: You might need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40397273/angular2-app-base-href-with-hashlocationstrategy

Comment: I did try using the provider, and am still testing it.

Comment: Unfortunately, that stackoverflow didn't solve the issue. When I tried it, I kept getting `this._platformLocation is undefined`. I also tried what you had suggested and it just kept making the second half longer and longer.

Answer (score 0):

Always your default route must be at the before the path "**".

```
 {path: '404', component: NotFoundComponent},
{path: '', redirectTo: 'patients', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent},
```

Refer
https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: I'm sure that's not true. What part in the linked document says that?

Comment: Maybe not but in my case i gave the default just before the wildcare route. Also check if redirectTo:’/patients’ works .... also pathMatch:’full’

Comment: It did not work for me. Having the base-ref set to '/' without any additional configuration means that it cannot find where the files are located (in directory ControlTower/NICK/UI). I also already have {path: ''} before everything else, including {path: '**'}.

If I keep <base href='#'> and no other build configurations, I can go to `https://clwd0002278/ControlTower/NICK/UI/#/` and it'll take me to /patients. BUT, if I go to that link from a new browser window, it'll immediately bootstrap and take me to `https://clwd0002278/ControlTower/NICK/UI/#/ControlTower/NICK/UI/`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer   **"The order of the routes in the configuration matters and this is by design. The router uses a first-match wins strategy when matching routes, so more specific routes should be placed above less specific routes. In the configuration above, routes with a static path are listed first, followed by an empty path route, that matches the default route. The wildcard route comes last because it matches every URL and should be selected only if no other routes are matched first."**  
Check the **Configuration** section in this link https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: @Darsandsk22 I didn't say anything else because that's the case, but the change you suggest, doesn't make a difference. It would make a difference without `pathMatch: 'full'`

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out that there was some code from ngrx that was pulled in from our base project package that kept throwing the location.pathname onto the end of the url for the angular/ngrx routing packages. I'm so frustrated and yet so relieved to have finally resolved this issue.

I commented out the reducers and initial state related to this to solve my issue. So, be careful of how ngrx interacts with your url!